# assign a list to a variable in loop

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop

I am trying to run a loop where I am using same list again and again. But the list is getting modified in every execution. So how can I assign a list to the same variable in every run.

```
import random

def fuse(a, row, col):
    a[row][col] = -a[row][col]
    return a

final_list = [[2,4],[5,6],[3,2],[1,0]]
for k in range(3):
    A = final_list[:]
    print A
    print final_list
    for i in range(len(A)-2):
        row = random.randint(0,len(A)-1)
        col = random.randint(1,len(A[row])-1)
        A = fuse(A,row,col)
```

In the above code A is getting modified in each run. But when I copy final_list to A and print A and final_list, they are different. I don't understand. I want to copy final_list exactly in A. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like your `fuse` function is wrong, if it modifies `A`.

Comment: I have to modify "A" in each run. But each run has to be independent. So for a fresh run I again need the same list

Comment: What do you mean "I can not assign final_list to A for each run"? Does that mean you're getting an error on the third line? Or that it isn't doing what you expected? Or that it does what you expected but you can't do it in your real code?

Comment: I mean if I put a statement "print A" just after " A = final_list[:]", after each execution I am getting different output of print

Comment: Can you give us a complete example (an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))? Because I'm having a hard time imagining how that could be true unless `fuse` is doing frame hacks or something even uglier…

Comment: Actually, the code doesn't just fail to demonstrate your problem it doesn't even run (even besides the trivial `IndentationError`) or make sense. If `final_list` is a list of numbers, and so is `A`, then what is `len(A[row])` supposed to mean?

Comment: Yes sorry for the confusion. Actually final_list is a list_of_lists and fuse actually modifies the list. Your answer below which explains that I need to copy list down to 2 levels answered the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted code doesn't actually demonstrate your problem. In fact, it can't actually run (no matter what `fuse` does) because `A[row]` is always going to be an `int`, so that `len(A[row])` is guaranteed to raise a `TypeError`.

But that makes it pretty obvious that in your *real* code, `final_list` is not a list of numbers, but a 2D list—a list of lists of numbers.

And that means `A = final_list[:]` is only copying the top-level list. So, you do get a new list—but it's a new list that references the exact same rows as the original list. So, if `fuse` mutates one of those rows, you're still mutating the original `final_list`.

You need to copy `final_list` down 2 levels, not just 1, like this:

```
A = [row[:] for row in final_list]
```

… or just deep-copy it:

```
A = copy.deepcopy(final_list)
```

---

Here's an example that actually does run, and demonstrates your problem:

```
import random

def fuse(a, row, col):
    a[row][col] = -a[row][col]
    return a

final_list = [[2,4],[5,6],[3,2],[1,0]]
for k in range(3):
    A = final_list[:]
    print A
    for i in range(len(A)-2):
        row = random.randint(0,len(A)-1)
        col = random.randint(1,len(A[row])-1)
        A = fuse(A,row,col)
```

And changing that `A = final_list[:]` to `A = copy.deepcopy(final_list)` (and adding the `import`, of course) now does what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly I what I want. This was my first stackoverflow question so didn't know how to provide all the details. Thank you again.

Comment: @Ankit: Read that [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) link. Your code has to actually demonstrate your problem, not just be kind of similar to code that demonstrates it in hopes that someone will guess. Even though you got an answer, you should still edit your question—both for the benefit of others with the same problem, and so that hopefully some people will upvote it instead of downvoting it.